# Убрать пробелы в начале и конце строки у текста в поле

Tags: java, android-edittext

Цель: Убрать пробелы написанные до слова и после, так же пустые строки.

Реализовывал через trim() подобным образом:

```
if(msg.trim().length() == 0){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Введите сообщение",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  m_edit_text_message.setText("");
  return;
}
```

Ошибка: При наличии символов в тексте, пробелы не удаляются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
```